# error: pathspec 'next/font Error in Next.js' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, next.js

I am currently using Next.js version 13.5.4. Every time I run the "npm run dev" command, I get the following error in my terminal:
"Your project has `@next/font` installed as a dependency, please use the built-in `next/font` instead. The `@next/font` package will be removed in Next.js 14. You can migrate by running `npx @next/codemod@latest built-in-next-font .`. Read more: [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/built-in-next-font"](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/built-in-next-font%22).

When I went to the link, I followed the procedure to correct the problem. However, when I try to commit my changes, I get the following error:
"error: pathspec 'next/font Error in Next.js' did not match any file(s) known to git"

Should I remove /.next/ from my .gitignore file? I've also seen that this problem could be caused by branch creation, but I haven't created any.

Comment: Show us your commit command as is.

Comment: that file path (`next/font Error in Next.js`) looks _extremely_ suspicious to me.

Comment: So I ran the command 'npx @next/codemod@latest built-in-next-font .' at the source of my project. Then I added my changes with 'git add .' and committed with 'git commit -m 'Resolving "Built-in next/font" Error in Next.js', at which point I ran into the following problem

Comment: @ImEmo try escaping `"` like `git commit -m 'Resolving \"Built-in next/font\" Error in Next.js'`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thank you very much, I was completely confused by the error message.

Comment: It's neither a git nor a nextjs error message